# How to allow pan using only specific key / mouse button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `InteractiveViewer` in flutter for creating a desktop app. When I press and drag the widget with any key using the mouse the widget starts panning (which is expected and normal). The question is how can I prevent the widget from panning if I drag for example using the right mouse button, but allow panning if I drag using the middle mouse button (i.e. when I press the mouse wheel down) ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample widget that will reproduce the issue?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh no need, what you are calling an issue is not "an issue", it is the normal behavior for this widget, so it does not need to be reproduced, what I need is a way to know, when on a desktop environment, what physical reason triggered the drag event, and prevent the drag event response if the reason was not the middle mouse click for example